# Groovy Builders vs Lisp/Scheme Code-as-data

Tags: groovy, scheme, racket, builder-pattern

This is a two part question having to do with "code as data".

I've been learning about Groovy's various builders (JSON, XML, CLI) and find their declarative syntax refreshing. Are Groovy's builders an example of "code is data"?

I've done a little Racket programming before and was wondering if Groovy's builder pattern could be easily migrated. I know about the `quote` and `unquote` features, but using those functions would mean the quoted code would be more of a "template" and not at the same level as the other code in the program (is there a term for this?). Is this where macros would come into play?

Comment: In scheme, code is data because its syntax for data and code isn't much different. The syntax of Scheme is so simple that we can almost say that writing code in Scheme is like writing code in abstract syntax tree directly. The fun thing about it is that you can use code as input to a program that will manipulate the code as data to output scheme code. Macros are exactly what's going on, it use the code as data and output scheme code that will be either evaled or compiled.

Comment: In simple, Scheme code can manipulate natively scheme code to ouput scheme code. You can transform the code as data and execute it as code. This allow schemer to extend the language in scheme itself. Unlike many other languages that are forced to extend the compiler/interpreter to understand new syntaxis.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix, thanks for the reply. In the case of Groovy's builders, they're not actually manipulating any syntax, so perhaps code-as-data is not the correct term in this case. I find it interesting that given an expressive syntax, macros wouldn't need to be used.